# How to use a MenuItem with child MenuItems when it has a custom ControlTemplate and is defined in a separate XAML file?

Tags: wpf, xaml, menuitem, controltemplate, visual-studio-2019

I have a MenuItem inside a Menu that should show a time span in its right side sometimes (a time span that decreases second by second). To make this change I created a new MenuItem subclass XAML file. In it I set the Template property of the MenuItem to the template that is created automatically by the Visual Studio when I click Edit Template > Edit a Copy... in the context menu of the menu item in the designer. When this template is set, the subitems, set directly in the MenuItem.Items property inside the new XAML file, do not show up, just like there has not been any child menu item added to it. I wish to use a template defined in XAML and also have child items at the same time.

[image: screenshot]

I tried to not put the child menu items in the new XAML file, but directly in the MainWindow.xaml, but I have reached [this limitation](https://robrelyea.wordpress.com/2007/06/21/building-a-control-which-holds-content-customcontrol-vs-markupsubclassing-vs-usercontrol/).

I also googled "wpf menuitem template with subitems" but with no success.

In MainWindow.xaml:

```xml
<MenuItem Header="_Window">
    <local:KeepOnTopMenuItem Header="_Keep on Top..." x:Name="MiKeepOnTop">
    </local:KeepOnTopMenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```

and all the markup in `KeepOnTopMenuItem.xaml`:

```xml
<MenuItem x:Class="cs_timed_silver.KeepOnTopMenuItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:cs_timed_silver"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="200" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}">
    <MenuItem.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Grid Margin="-1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                    <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#FF26A0DA" BorderThickness="1" Background="#3D26A0DA" ClipToBounds="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="22">
                        <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="#FF212121" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="10"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="remainingTimeSpanText" Grid.Column="5" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="gray"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#FF707070"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#0A000000"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#21000000"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </MenuItem.Resources>
    <MenuItem.Items>
        <MenuItem Command="local:CustomCommands.KeepOnTopAlways"
                CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
                IsCheckable="True"
                x:Name="MiKeepOnTopAlways"/>
        <MenuItem Command="local:CustomCommands.KeepOnTopUntilNextRestart"
                CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
                IsCheckable="True"
                Name="MiKeepOnTopUntilNextRestart"/>
        <MenuItem IsCheckable="True"
                Command="local:CustomCommands.KeepOnTopFor5Min"
                CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
                x:Name="MiKeepOnTopFor5Min"/>
        <MenuItem IsCheckable="True"
                Command="local:CustomCommands.KeepOnTopFor15Min"
                CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
                x:Name="MiKeepOnTopFor15Min"/>
        <MenuItem IsCheckable="True"
                Command="local:CustomCommands.KeepOnTopFor1Hour"
                CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
                x:Name="MiKeepOnTopFor1Hour"/>
    </MenuItem.Items>

    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="/Resources/Oxygen-Icons.org-Oxygen-Actions-go-top.ico"/>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

The expected result is that the submenu items are shown and the actual result is that the KeepOnTopMenuItem shows up as without child items.

I am not sure what to do next. What can I do to use custom MenuItem template together with child items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit Template->Edit a Copy doesn't give you the right template.

If you use a decompiler such as [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and open `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll`, you'll find the default templates in `themes/aero2.normalcolor.baml`.

If you look at the `MenuItem` template, you'll se that it applies a different `ControlTemplate` based on the value of the `Role` property:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="MenuItem.Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template"
                Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}, ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.Padding" Value="6,0"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="MenuItem.Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template"
                Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}, ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.Padding" Value="6,0"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="MenuItem.Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template"
                Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}, ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

It's one of these templates that you should customize in order not to break the default behaviour.